# Why is the css code for parallax not working correctly on an iPad?

Tags: css

I am working on site right now.  http://jandswebsitedesigns.com/gllaw/

The parallax works great on desktop and laptop, but not on ipad.  I am new at this and not sure what to do. I found this snippet of code on the internet.  I am using it for parallax effect.  As I mentioned,  it works and looks great on my laptop,  but when I tried to view it on an ipad.  There something wrong withe the css but I am not sure what the problem is.  The image "main-bg4.jpg" is not displaying correctly.  I am totally confused about this one.

```css
.parallax {
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url("images/main-bg4.jpg");
  /* Set a specific height */
  min-height: 600px;
  /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.parallax2 {
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url("images/law-offices-bldg.jpg");
  /* Set a specific height */
  min-height: 600px;
  /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div id="hdr">
  <div class="hdr-container">
    <div class="hdr-left">
      <div style="font-size:  18px; color:  #ffffff; font-family:  arial narrow; padding-left: 5px;">Law Offices of</div>
      <div class="atty-tags">Gonzalez &amp; Lopez, LLP</div>

    </div>
    <div class="hdr-right">
      <div class="nav-div">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="firm-overview.html">Firm Overview</a></li>
          <li><a href="personal-injury-attorney.html">Personal Injury</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="family-law-attorney.html">Family Law</a></li>
          <li><a href="business-litigation-attorney.html">Business Law</a>
          </li>

          <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <!--div class="callus">Call us today (361) 906-9107</div-->
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<!-- close hdr-->

<div class="parallax" style="position: relative; z-index:  -1;">
</div>

<div id="services">
  <div class="services-container">
    <div class="left-section">
      <a href="personal-injury-attorney.html"><img src="images/personal-injury-main.jpg" alt="personal injury 
     corpus christi" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="mid-section">
      <a href="family-law-attorney.html"><img src="images/family-law-services.jpg" alt="personal injury corpus christi" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="right-section">
      <a href="business-litigation-attorney.html"><img src="images/business-law-services2.jpg" alt="personal injury 
    corpus christi" /></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You probably don't mean for it to, but this looks a lot like spam, giving the embedded URLs and phone numbers. Please try reducing your code to something easier to replicate.

Comment: I am not sure what you are telling me.  I was thinking some part of the css is not working for ipads.  Please elaborate.